# How to validate google places AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, google-places

i think it may silly question for some people but i don't know why i'm not getting it. My question is, i'm getting the latitude and longitude by google places api

**Code:**

```
Geocoder geoCoder new Geocoder(this);
AutoCompleteTextView fAPSearchLocationEt;


        fAPSearchLocationLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            try {

                List<Address> returnedaddresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(fAPSearchLocationEt.getText().toString(),1);

                if(returnedaddresses != null){

                    String latForVol = String.valueOf(returnedaddresses.get(0).getLatitude());
                    String longForVol = String.valueOf(returnedaddresses.get(0).getLongitude());

                    Log.e("Lat", latForVol);
                    Log.e("Long", longForVol);

                }else {
                    Log.e("Long", "Please give the correct address");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    });
```

So, now i want to validate the AutoCompleteTextView

**Explanation for validation:**

For suppose user gave the wrong address like `sadgdfhsfagAGDSFJDGHMSFSDFGsdfhg` or any other. So, in this case i want to validate the correct address when setOnClickListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this by

```
try {
                    List<Address> returnedaddresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(fAPSearchLocationEt.getText().toString(),1);

                    if(!returnedaddresses.isEmpty()){

                        String latForVol = String.valueOf(returnedaddresses.get(0).getLatitude());
                        String longForVol = String.valueOf(returnedaddresses.get(0).getLongitude());

                        Log.e("Lat", latForVol);
                        Log.e("Long", longForVol);
                        Log.e("Location", fAPSearchLocationEt.getText().toString());

                    }else {
                        Log.e("Long", "Please give the correct address");
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Places will automatically does this task. If you going to validate "sadgdfhsfagAGDSFJDGHMSFSDFGsdfhg" this kind of thing then you have to implement lots of logic.

Simply use "ResultCallback" in code:-

```
 private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
        = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
        if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " +
                    places.getStatus().toString());
            return;
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: it's not going to the onResult method, can you explain me how to use it in my code

Comment: @kiran, If you need then i can send you entire code for that.